# Continuous linear functionals

Tags: metric-spaces, continuity, topological-vector-spaces

Let L be a continuous  linear functional on a metric linear space X. Prove:  L(S) is a bounded set for any bounded subset S of X. The metric is translation invariant.

Comment: How do you mean *linear* on a *metric space*?

Comment: Presumably you mean on a vector space with a metric?

Comment: I corrected the question. It now reads "...metric linear space" instead of "metric space"

Comment: Is the metric compatible with the linear structure, that is do you assume that the addition and scalar multiplication are continuous functions?

Comment: Yes. I think that is the definition of a metric linear space.

Comment: I suppose *bounded* means *bounded in the [topological vector space sense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_set_(topological_vector_space))*, right?

Comment: Isn't it the same? Neighborhoods are built up by balls.

Comment: @Berci: no, it's not the same. In your example $(\mathbb{R},d')$ the entire line is bounded with respect to the metric, but it is *not* absorbed by *every* neighborhood of zero. There is no scalar $\lambda$ such that $\mathbb{R} \subseteq \lambda B$, where $B$ is the ball of radius $1/2$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that this is true in general for $L:X\rightarrow Y$ linear continuous between two metric linear spaces.

Hints:

- fix an open ball centered at $0$ (the one of radius $1$ for instance)
- use continuity at $0$.
- prove that $L$ is bounded on some open ball $B$ centered at $0$.
- use that for every bounded set $S$, there is $\rho>0$ such that $S\subset \rho B$.

Comment: Taking the last bullet as given the proof is very easy. So, how do you show the last bullet?

Comment: @mas In the view of Martin and Berci comments, I think you should clarify what you mean by *bounded*.

Answer (score -1):

Consider the inverse image of any bounded open neighborhood $W$ of $0$ in the target space (let it be $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$ or anything). Its preimage, $L^{-1}(W)$ is an open neighborhood of $0\in X$, so it contains a *ball* $B(\varepsilon)$ around $0$ with radius some $\ \varepsilon >0$. Let us fix this $\varepsilon$.

Now, if we have any bounded set $S\subseteq X$, then there exists a ball that contains it, say with radius $r_0>0$ and midpoint $Q$, then  $\ S\subseteq B(r)\ $ where $\ r=r_0+d(0,Q)$.

Now imagine the continuous mappings $f_\lambda:X\to X,\ \ v\mapsto \lambda\cdot v$. If $\lambda\neq 0$,  it is a homeomorphism, mapping any ball $B(\rho)$ (around $0$) to an open set, which also contains a ball around $0$, say with radius $f(\lambda,\rho)>0$. So that $B(\lambda\cdot\rho)=f_\lambda(B(\rho))\supseteq B(f(\lambda,\rho))$...

Then,  $L(S)\subseteq L(B(r))= L(f_{\frac r\varepsilon}( B(\varepsilon))) \subseteq f(\displaystyle\frac r\varepsilon)\cdot  W $, bounded.

---

**Update:** Hmm, in this generality it is **not true**. Let $X=\Bbb R$ with a *bounded* metric, for example $d'(x,y):=\displaystyle\frac{d(x,y)}{1+d(x,y)} <1$, and let $L$ be the identity $X\to\Bbb R$. Then the whole $X$ is *bounded*, but its image is not bounded.

Comment: Why is $B(r)=\frac{r}{\epsilon}B(\epsilon)$? You have to have some extra assumptions about the metric, I think.

Comment: Exactly. You cannot assume that. You only know that you are in a metric linear space, and you cannot assume d(ax,0)=ad(x,0).

Comment: Aha.. a bit unusual to me, I am going to think it over..

Comment: I started to prove, then got to the point to see that it is not true. Also added counterexample.

Comment: Ok, then it's a hint, probably this new condition  of translation invariance implies surjectivity of $f(\lambda,\rho)$, and then one can prove that scalar multiplications preserve *bounded* sets, that is the missing point.

Comment: Just to let you know, I do not have a proof for it. The metric in the counter example is not invariant.

Comment: Hey wait, if it is translation invariant, it also means that $d(0,n\cdot x)\le n\cdot d(0,x)$ for all $x$, no? But then you can use the earlier reasonging with the upper integer part of $\frac r\varepsilon$ or something like that.

Comment: I think there is a confusion between two largely unrelated notions of "bounded": bounded with respect to the metric and [bounded in the topological vector space sense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_set_(topological_vector_space)). For bounded sets in the second sense the assertion is true, but, as you observe, not for bounded sets in the first sense. // Your metric $d'$ is translation invariant, but it isn't homogeneous.